# cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

[image]
.cs project file

The project was created using Visual Studio 2010 and I am trying to open it in Visual Studio 2010 itself but still I am facing this problem.

I have opened this project in VS 2012 and worked for few days but it has created in Visual studio 2010. Is there anything which preserve the project details on local machine?

This is the specific project section in my solution file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00 
# Visual Studio 2010 
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Project Name", "Project Name\project name.csproj", "{48C1190E-7700-461B-ADCD-B5E0F1ECAD21}" 
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject 
        {1F5440B3-9FD8-4FE2-B621-8697489ABDC4} = {1F5440B3-9FD8-4FE2-B621-8697489ABDC4} 
    EndProjectSection 
EndProject
```

Comment: The [project type GUIDs](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs) indicate that this project is both a ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASP.NET MVC 5 project which seems strange to me. Try removing one of the GUIDs and see whether the problem is resolved.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Project Name", "Project Name\project name.csproj", "{48C1190E-7700-461B-ADCD-B5E0F1ECAD21}"
 ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
  {1F5440B3-9FD8-4FE2-B621-8697489ABDC4} = {1F5440B3-9FD8-4FE2-B621-8697489ABDC4}
 EndProjectSection
EndProject

Comment: This is the specific project section in my solution file

Comment: the problem get solved by just removing project GUID for MVC5, Thanks Dirk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio it is possible to add Project Types, e.g. for creating an MSI, by installing an Add-On to the development machine. It appears that in the past this was done, and then that new Project Type was used to add a Project to the Solution. But now you are opening the Solution on a machine that does not have that new Project Type.

Look for the GUID of the missing Project Type, it should be part of the error you are getting. Then google "project type {the-guid}" to see which Add-On you need to install on your development machine.

It is also possible that a new Project Type was used in the Solution that simply can not work with VS 2010. In that case your options are either to keep using VS2012, or to start over with a new Solution in VS2010 and migrate the projects into it that are compatible (which may be a bit tricky or hard to do if VS2012 saved them).

Answer (score 0):

Would it be too difficult to just recreate the project and include all the necessary files and references?  Once the project was saved from VS 2012, the format may have broken compatibility with 2010.  Sometimes this is fixable just by updating the version number in the project file, but I don't see it in your image.